# bot framework - working with source or multiple knowledge base

Tags: c#, botframework, bots, azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

I'm working on a QnA bot using the bot framework in c# and I have multiple FAQs with similar, or even the same, questions with different answers. So I'm working on a way to better segregate data and currently I see two options:

1. Use the same knowledge base and segregate questions by source
2. Use multiple knowledge bases

The second option seems the way to go but requires more development time and cost to host the KB, so I would like to experiment with the first option. The problem is, I didn't find any kind of way to filter or segregate answers by source. Does anyone have tried working with it and found any success?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is, I didn't find any kind of way to filter or segregate answers by source.

The knowledge base answer can differ based on the [metadata tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/metadata-generateanswer-usage#metadata-example), even if the query is the same. You can try to segregate answers by adding different metadata to your question/answer sets.

[image]

To [filter answers using metadata](https://github.com/garypretty/botframework/tree/master/QnAMakerDialog#boosting-and-filtering-answers-using-metadata), you can refer to the following sample code.

***In MessagesController:***

```
[BotAuthentication]
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
    internal static IDialog<object> MakeRoot()
    {
        var qnaDialog = new Dialogs.MyQnADialog
        {
            MetadataFilter = new List<Metadata>()
            {
                new Metadata()
                {
                    Name = "knowledgebase",
                    Value = "base1"

                    //Name = "knowledgebase",
                    //Value = "base2"
                }
            }
        };

        return qnaDialog;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// POST: api/Messages
    /// Receive a message from a user and reply to it
    /// </summary>
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, MakeRoot);
        }
        else
        {
            HandleSystemMessage(activity);
        }
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }

    //......
    // other code logic
    //......
}
```

***In QnAMakerDialog:***

```
[Serializable]
[QnAMakerService("https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker/", "{EndpointKey_here}", "{KnowledgeBaseId_here}",1)]
public class MyQnADialog : QnAMakerDialog<object>
{
    public override async Task NoMatchHandler(IDialogContext context, string originalQueryText)
    {
        await context.PostAsync($"Sorry, I couldn't find an answer for '{originalQueryText}'.");
        context.Done(false);
    }

    public override async Task DefaultMatchHandler(IDialogContext context, string originalQueryText, QnAMakerResult result)
    {
        if (result.Answers.FirstOrDefault().Score > 80)
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"I found {result.Answers.Length} answer(s) that might help...{result.Answers.First().Answer}.");
        }
        else
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"Sorry, I couldn't find an answer for '{originalQueryText}'.");
        }

        context.Done(true);
    }
}
```

***Test result:***

*1)with Metadata `knowledgebase:base1`*

[image]

*2)with Metadata `knowledgebase:base2`*

[image]

***Note:*** *I'm using [QnAMakerDialog -Version 3.1.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/QnAMakerDialog/)*

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you for your answer!